# cannot refresh the recyclveiw from inside fragment?

Tags: java, android

I display data inside the fragment at first I used some functions within the function on Create View and everything became perfect and succeeded in fetching and displaying data, but when I call the adpter from within another function to try to do a re-display and update data happens errors,
specifically, a problem occurs when I press the button inside the dialog,
 please help

```
    //CustomerAdapter class 
    public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        public final int TYPE_MOVIE = 0;
        public final int TYPE_LOAD = 1;

        static Context context;
        List<Customer>customers;
        OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
        boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;

        public CustomerAdapter(Context context, List<Customer> customers) {
            this.context = context;
            this.customers = customers;
        }

        public void refreshEvents(List<Customer> data) {
            clear();
            addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if(viewType==TYPE_MOVIE){
                return new CustomerHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie,parent,false));
            }else{
                return new LoadHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_load,parent,false));
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            if(position>=getItemCount()-1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener!=null){
                isLoading = true;
                loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
            }


            if(getItemViewType(position)==TYPE_MOVIE){
                ((CustomerHolder)holder).bindData(customers.get(position));

                if(((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption != null)((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                  //  function call a volly function .. //..
                  // if(customers.get(position).user_id==2)((CustomerHolder)holder).imgLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  ((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption.getRootView().toString();
               //    Toast.makeText(context,"Index Is "+customers.get(position).status+"usr_id"+customers.get(position).user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Page_6Fragment.newInstance().sendNotfic(context ,customers.get(position).user_id);
                       // Call a fucntion to
                  Page_6Fragment.newInstance().showDialog(context,customers.get(position).user_id , Integer.parseInt(customers.get(position).id));
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if(customers.get(position).type.equals("movie")){
                return TYPE_MOVIE;
            }else{
                return TYPE_LOAD;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){

           return customers.size();
        }

        /* VIEW HOLDERS */

        static class CustomerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvRating;
            ImageView imgLock;
            //  int usrid;

            Button buttonViewOption;

            public CustomerHolder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
                tvTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                tvRating=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
                imgLock=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_lock);
                buttonViewOption = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
            }


            void bindData(Customer cust){
               tvTitle.setText(cust.name);
               tvRating.setText(cust.title);
               // if(cust.user_id==2)imgLock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(cust.status!=0)buttonViewOption.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lock));
                //  imgLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


        static class LoadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public LoadHolder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
            }
        }

        public void setMoreDataAvailable(boolean moreDataAvailable) {
            isMoreDataAvailable = moreDataAvailable;
        }

        /* notifyDataSetChanged is final method so we can't override it
             call adapter.notifyDataChanged(); after update the list
        */

        public void notifyDataChanged(){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            isLoading = false;
        }
        public interface OnLoadMoreListener{
            void onLoadMore();
        }


        public void setLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener) {
            this.loadMoreListener = loadMoreListener;
        }
    }


    // Fragment class : 
    public class Page_6Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        TextView t1,t2,t3,t4;
        Spinner spin,spin2,spin3,spin4;
        Dialog dialog;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        List<Customer>customers;
        CustomerAdapter adapter;
        View rootView;
        String TAG = "MainActivity - ";
        Context context;
        API api;
        Activity a;
        Boolean acceptOrNo = true;
        Context c =null;

        public static Page_6Fragment newInstance(){

            Page_6Fragment fragment = new Page_6Fragment();

            return fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer, container, false);
            //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.xml.pref, container, false);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceDemoActivity.this,PrefsActivity.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
            this.context = getActivity();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            customers = new ArrayList<>();
            adapter = new CustomerAdapter(context,customers);
            adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new CustomerAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener(){
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore() {
                    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int index = customers.size();
                          loadMore(index);
                        }
                    });
                    //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
                }
            });
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            api = ServiceGenerator.createService(API.class);
            load(0);
          return rootView;
        }


    //  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalLineDecorator(2));

        private void load(int index){

            Call<List<Customer>> call = api.getCustomer(index);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, final Response<List<Customer>> response){
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //Log.i("TRUE_TRUE_","Yes "+response.body().get(2).name);
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                     //Log.i("TRUE_TRUE3","Yes"+response.body().toString());
                     //movies.addAll(response.body());
                     //adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                     getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                      // No.1 ..............
                      // ShowDataScreen();
                       // Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "ShowDataScreen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           customers.addAll(response.body());
                            adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                             }});// end of No.1 UI new thread
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {//No.2
                               // Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "This is correct way",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }});// end of No.2 UI new thread
                          // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }


        public void showDialog(final Context context , final int getToken , final int id){
            dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            // dialog.setTitle("استقبال الطلب");
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
            dialog.show();
            String[] bankNames = {
                    "O","B","H","N","j"
            };
            t1= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_h);
            t2= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_m);
            t3= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            t4= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_pam);
            spin =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes);
            spin2 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes2);
            spin3 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes3);
            spin4 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tex);
            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spin4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.second2);
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.second);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
            ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.spinner_item,bankNames);
            //ArrayAdapter b = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,bankNames2);
            //a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //spin.setAdapter(a);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(checkedId);
                    if (checkedId == R.id.second2) {
                       RadioYes();
                       acceptOrNo = false;
                    } else if (checkedId == R.id.second) {
                       acceptOrNo = true;
                       RadioNo();
                 }
                }
            });


            Button btnOk = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
            btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.i("trace_u",""+acceptOrNo);
            if(acceptOrNo)sendNotfic(context , id , getToken ,"1" , spin4.getSelectedItem().toString() ,  "الساعه"+spin.getSelectedItem().toString()+":"+spin2.getSelectedItem().toString()+" "+spin3.getSelectedItem().toString());
            else
            sendNotfic(context , id , getToken ,"2","--" ,"--");
            dialog.dismiss();

                    /// Update Rview
                   // if(adapter != null) {
                       adapter.refreshEvents(customers);
                    //}

                }
            });


            Button btnNo = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_set);
            btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    /*
                    adapter = new CustomerAdapter(context , customers);
                    Log.i("adapter_",""+adapter);
                    if(adapter != null) {
                        Log.i("adpter_33","yesysy");
                        adapter.refreshEvents();
                    }
    */
              }
            });
        }

// Loge cat : 

 Process: com.example.android.wacher, PID: 2519
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.wacher.adapters.CustomerAdapter.refreshEvents(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.android.wacher.fragments.Page_6Fragment$8.onClick(Page_6Fragment.java:312)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22259)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onBindViewHolder` you have this line

```
Page_6Fragment.newInstance().showDialog(context,customers.get(position).user_id , Integer.parseInt(customers.get(position).id));
```

In this line you create new instance of `Page_6Fragment` where you didn't initialize the adapter yet, You try to show dialog and in the button listener you refresh a null adapter

**Solution 1:**
Pass a callback function to the adapter, which is implemented in the fragment

**Solution 2:**
You can pass the fragment as a parameter to the adapter and call the method directly instead of creating new instance of the fragment

Change the constructor to

```
public CustomerAdapter(Page_6Fragment page_6Fragment, List<Customer> customers) {
    // You can get context from page_6Fragment.getContext()
    // And No need to make the context or the fragment static
}
```

And in `onBindViewHolder`
Call the method this way

```
page_6Fragment.showDialog(context,customers.get(position).user_id , Integer.parseInt(customers.get(position).id));
```

And in the fragment when you initialize the adapter

```
adapter = new CustomerAdapter(Page_6Fragment.this,customers);
```

Comment: Thanks for you , can you to insert sample code for Solution 2